# Multiple array search

Tags: php, arrays

```
$text=$_REQUEST['text'];
$ar=array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z);
$f = array_search($text, $ar);
echo $f;
```

If I will type in the field 'text' - "a" it will show me array number - 0;
but if I will type 'ab' it will not find anything. Is there way to find multiple values in array at one time?

Comment: Have you tried something to solve it yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = $_REQUEST['text']; // ab
$ar = range('a','z');
$f = array_intersect($ar, str_split($text, 1));
var_dump($f);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/AR8VfR)